# Covariance and virtual inheritance causing ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to use covariance alongside virtual inheritance?

Here is a simplified scenario.

```
class A{};

class B : public virtual A {};

class C : public virtual A {};

class D : public B, public C {};



class CoreA
{
protected:
    virtual A& Get() = 0;
};

class CoreB : public virtual CoreA {
    virtual B& Get() = 0;
};

class CoreC : public virtual CoreA {
    virtual C& Get() = 0;
};

class CoreD : public CoreB, public CoreC
{
public:
    virtual D& Get() override { return d; }
protected:
    D d;
};
```

I am running into an ambiguity problem due to both CoreB's and CoreC's Get functions.  If they are removed, there are no more errors, but I need those Get functions.

I have been able to resolve the issue by renaming the Get functions inside of CoreB and CoreC, while overriding them in CoreD

```
class CoreB : public virtual CoreA {
    virtual B& Get_B() = 0;
};

class CoreC : public virtual CoreA {
    virtual C& Get_C() = 0;
};

class CoreD : public CoreB, public CoreC
{
public:
    virtual D& Get_B() override { return d; }
    virtual D& Get_C() override { return d; }
    virtual D& Get() override { return d; }
protected:
    D d;
};
```

Does anyone know of a cleaner workaround?

Comment: The code you wrote above works on ideone (gcc).

Comment: _I have been able to resolve the issue by renaming the Get functions inside of CoreB and CoreC, while overriding them in CoreD_ So ... what's the problem?  (Other than an inheritance tree which I personally would seek to simplify).

Comment: Fair enough... I mostly found it odd that such a problem would occur.  If one wanted to instantiate CoreB, they wouldn't be able to, due to Get being a pure virtual function. However, this could also be resolved by creating a derived class of CoreB and implementing the Get function. @PaulSanders

Comment: Well, functions with the same name and signature but different return types are illegal, period.  As for making `Get` pure virtual in your base class, well, you don't have to if you don't want to.  An empty implementation is a viable alternative (and not uncommon), depends what you want.  There are many ways to skin that particular cat.

Comment: (Ugh, horrible expression, sorry)

Comment: @PaulSanders C++ allows covariant returns type where a derived class override a function but the return type is a class derived from the type the base class returns. This is known as covariant as specified in the question.  Search **covariant return type** on Google.

Comment: @Phil1970 OK, thanks, I didn't know that.  I've never dared try :)  OP please ignore [most of] my previous comment.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 also give a similar errors. The fact that multiple compilers gave errors on it clearly indicate that **you are going a bit too far**... I am not sure if standard allows that code. Probably unspecified...

Answer (score 0):

[Reported Issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Compiler-Error-C2250---Unable-to-resolve/10109726) to Microsoft under Developer Community

> Unfortunately, this is a limitation in MSVC’s object model and requires ABI breaking changes to support.
> You can consider writing your own covariant wrapper to work around.